# How to create more templates to the same theme?

Tags: theme-development

Some theme contains more than one templates to chose in Page editor.
[image]

What is this called? How can I register more templates to my theme?

Comment: Please ignore me, I just find out the doc about it (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create .php file with name like `template-blogs.php`, inside file write a `Template Name` in php comment, include header & footer.
here is the sample of test template

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Test Template
*/
get_header();
?>
<div class="content_area">
   <!---Write Your PHP Code Here--->
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: And one of the important thing is the `/* Template Name: Bla Bla Bla */` part right?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help you! Kindly mark it as answer.

Comment: For sure, I'm just waiting "cooldown" to mark it.